# Meaning of “have the greatest of difficulty”

Tags: word-usage

I’m learning a passage talking about William Shakespeare. There’s a sentence in it which I’m confused about the meaning and usage. Here’s the sentence:

> It is a popular place for tourists from all over the world, even
>   though many of them would have the greatest of difficulty in
>   understanding Shakespeare’s Elizabethan English.

I have no idea why the author use “the greatest of difficulty” instead of “the greatest difficulty.”

Comment: genitive construnctions like "of the gods" is mentioned in wikipedia as a predecessor for superlativs (Germanic \*ster is an unexplained innovation not reconstrutable for the parent language stage), also cp "of all". I suspect this echos back in constructions such as that.

Comment: There's no question in your post. Word-usage of "of" would be an immensly broad topic. It might serve multiple purposes on multiple levels of speech production and in multiple concuring interpretations. Asking why not x instead is useless as answering how about z, take z

Comment: I don't know why the writer added 'of', but it doesn't change the meaning.